# probability density and ML mapping

Tags: probability, probability-density

I am trying to solve the below question. Please help me with this.

A pixel in a particular image has a random brightness, `X`. The distribution of `X`depends on
whether the pixel belongs to an object (`O`) of interest or the background (`B`). If it belongs to
the object, then `X` has a Laplace distribution,

```
*fX(x|O) = (a/2)exp(-a|x|), -infinity<x<infinity
```

where `a = 0:2`. If the pixel belongs to the background, then `X` is uniformly distributed
between `-10` and `10`.
Consider the problem of classifying a pixel based on an observation of its brightness, `X = x`.

1. Find the `ML` rule for all values of `x` and illustrate the decision regions on the real line.
2. Find the probability of error if the `ML` decision rule is used, but the probability that the
   pixel belongs to the object of interest is equal to `0.6`.